# How can a page and custom post type share the same parent

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, taxonomy, slug

I'm running into an interesting 404 error which I can't get my head around. I created a custom post type 'reizen'. I've set a page as its parent with a rewrite:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'oeganda/reizen'),
```

All works perfectly. So now all my **CPT pages** have the right URL *"../oeganda/reizen/page-name/"*. But now I also want **regular pages** to have **"reizen"** as its parent. But all regular pages with *"oeganda/reizen"* as their parents now get 404-errors. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default the custom posts type root page doesn't exist. There is no custom posts type index page. Upon trying to reach it will return a `404.php` page.

By creating a blank page called "`oeganda`" and a blank page called "`reizen`" with "`oeganda`" as parent, you should be able, when you create a new default blank page and set the parent as "`reizen`" to get the wanted url.

Comment: Thanks for responding. That is actually how it's currently set up. But apparently the slug rewrite for the CPT conflicts with any other page that's nested under the 'reizen' page.
For now I have fixed the issue by giving the CPT an even deeper path with the slug rewrite: "oeganda/reizen/reis/".
With a redirect from reis to reizen everything works fine now. Not ideal, but it works :-)